# How to use SELECT INTO to copy keys

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this

```
SELECT * INTO VendorsBackup
from Vendors
```

This works but it doesn't copy the key definitions to the new table. How I can do that with SELECT INTO?

Comment: You can't. You need to script the keys. It won't copy the computed columns definitions either.

Comment: You can script a table relatively easy using the UI of course. or SSIS

Comment: Select INTO copies the data, not the table structure. The only table structure element is that it will bring over the identity property in some situations.

Answer (score 0):

Copying the data from the table, it would be hard for sql to know that the same indexes and relationships need to be built. You should be able to right click on the original table and click on script as create, from there you will have all the relationships and can then apply them to the new table if needed. I would imagine that there is a way to do this via a script as well, but would be a little more complex going through the schema tables.

Comment: Why would it be hard for SQL to know what indexes need to be built?

Comment: @nicomp The "From" part of the query could be more complex. In your scenario, it looks like a simple table, but if you joined other tables together, calculated results, or used subqueries, etc. it wouldn't be able to predict what the desired indexes would be.